# How to full uninstall Truffle?

Tags: solidity, truffle, consensys-truffle

I try to uninstall Truffle because i need a older version. I tried with 'npm uninstall -g truffle' but after that checking the version is still installed

Comment: looks like duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45932/unable-to-uninstall-truffle
refer to the link

Answer (score 0):

If it's linux
try

```
which truffle
```

in windows
`where truffle`

and remove the file which is displayed as above commands output
and try installing your required version with `npm i truffle@<version> -g`